# generate random LocalTime in a specific range

Tags: java, localtime

I have two LocalTime objects:

```
LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.of(8, 0, 0);
LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.of(15, 0, 0);
```

and I want to generate a random LocalTime object between these two objects.

I already tried to do it with `rand.nexInt()`

```
Random rand = new Random();

int hours = rand.nextInt((time2.getHour() - time1.getHour()) + 1) + time1.getHour();
int minutes =  rand.nextInt((time2.getMinute() - time1.getMinute()) + 1) + time1.getMinute();
int seconds = rand.nextInt((time2.getSecond() - time1.getSecond()) + 1) + time1.getSecond(); 

LocalTime random = LocalTime.of(hours,minutes,seconds);
```

but only full hours like `9:00:00` will be generated.

Comment: Pick random numbers for hours, minutes, and seconds. [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/363681)

Comment: How fine-grained? Take for example `ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(time1, time2)` to find how many seconds, that is, how many times there are on whole seconds. Then `Random.nextInt(countOfSeconds)` to decide how long from `time1`. Then `time1.plusSeconds` to add them. Or use hours, minutes, milliseconds or nanoseoncds as you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check that `time2` is after `time1`.
Then you could convert the `LocalTime` instances into a `long` representing the number of second of the day (`LocalTime.toSecondOfDay()` method does that), then pick a random number between the  number of second of the day of the two `LocalTime` instances and use `LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay()` to create the random `LocalTime`.

```
LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.of(8, 0, 0);
LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.of(15, 0, 0);
int secondOfDayTime1 = time1.toSecondOfDay();
int secondOfDayTime2 = time2.toSecondOfDay();
Random random = new Random();
int randomSecondOfDay = secondOfDayTime1 + random.nextInt(secondOfDayTime2-secondOfDayTime1);   
LocalTime randomLocalTime = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(randomSecondOfDay);
```

Note that in `Random.next(int bound)`, the `bound` value is exclusive. So if it matter, you should add one second to include the last value in the possible range such as :

```
int randomSecondOfDay = 
secondOfDayTime1 + random.nextInt(secondOfDayTime2-secondOfDayTime1 + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long totalNanos = Math.abs(ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(time1, time2));
long randomNanos = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(totalNanos);
LocalTime firstTime = time2.isAfter(time1) ? time1 : time2;
LocalTime randomTime = firstTime.plusNanos(randomNanos);
System.out.println(randomTime);
```

When I ran the code just now, it printed

> 14:29:55.815373666

If you want it less fine-grained, you may do similarly with milliseconds or seconds, minutes or even hours. The reason why I am using `ThreadLocalRandom` is this offers a random long within a bound. For milliseconds or greater you can convert to `int` and use the standard `Random` class instead if you like.

I have assumed a half-open interval, that is, the result will sometimes (seldom) be equal to `time1` and never to `time2`. Can I leave it to you to add or subtract 1 in the right places if you want something else? [davidxxx’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51381347/5772882) also treats this issue.

Comment: No need to be restrictive about the order of arguments. I've fixed it for you

Comment: I suppose this will have to depend on the requirements in the concrete situation, @Michael. Only the asker can tell which is better.